# Spark dataframe - avoid shuffle when using groupBy on union of two dataframes

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Let's say I have two spark dataframes as follows :

df1:

```
ID | val
A  |  x1
C  |  y1
B  |  z1
...
```

df2:

```
ID | val
A  |  x2
C  |  y2
B  |  z2
...
```

Not really important but df2 does not necessarily have all the df1 IDs

Now we want to add df2 values to df1 ( for instance with some collect_list), we now have something like this (pseudo spark code) :

```
df = df1.unionByName(df2)
df = df.groupBy(ID).agg(F.collect(val))
```

The full picture is that we do that iteratively as follows :

```
df_previous_day = spark.read.parquet(...)
while(range of days):
  df_current_day = spark.read.parquet(.../someday)
  df_previous_day = df_previous_day.unionByName(df_current_day).groupBy(ID).agg(F.collect(val))
...
```

The thing is that this groupBy will cause lot of shuffle and we want to avoid that as much as possible. Besides, we're not really sure the above is the best approach.

The question:
Do you think that maybe bucketing would help here to avoid shuffle while doing the groupBy ? Do you know how to avoid breaking the buckets benefits while using unionByName. Should we union using two dataframes bucketed the same way to achieve this ?

Comment: A good example to try this for yourself is in https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/content/spark-sql-bucketing.html